# MomentJS toISOString AM/PM Incorrect

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, momentjs

I am trying to set the default time in the `<iondatetime>` field so that, when the user taps the field to change the time, the default time show is the current time selected. However, in trying to do so, the times are appearing incorrect for anything after 12PM.

The times are stored in the database as UTC. I also want them to be shown as they are in the database and not converted to the local time based on the device. I have tried both keeping the default offset and not keeping it but both of these failed:

```
data[key]['time_start'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').toISOString(false);

data[key]['time_start'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').toISOString(true);
```

When using `data[key]['time_start'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').toISOString(true);`, here's the results (left column is what is stored in the database - right column is after conversion):

```
08:00:00 - 2019-07-25T08:00:00.000-07:00
09:30:00 - 2019-07-25T09:30:00.000-07:00
17:30:00 - 2019-07-25T05:30:00.000-07:00
19:30:00 - 2019-07-25T07:30:00.000-07:00
```

It's subtracting 12 from anything over 12 which would effectively turn the time into 12 hour instead of 24 hour however, it's not working when displaying. When I using `<iondatetime>` with *displayFormat="h:mma"* it's still showing `5:30a` and `7:30a`. Even if I change it to *displayFormat="HH:mmA"* is still shows `5:30a` and `7:30a`.

I am expecting to see `5:30p` and `7:30p` which would be the correct times.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/7rxym0kL/. If you visit the JSFiddle link, do you get the correct results or the same results you see in your question?

Comment: Hm, that's crazy weird. What your jsfiddle shows is accurate which makes me wonder why mine is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it! Stupid me. I was modifying `data[key]['time']` first and that was causing the problem. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being me modifying the initial time from the database prior to converting it to an ISO string.

```
data[key]['time'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mma');
data[key]['time_start'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').toISOString(true);
```

Should be:

```
data[key]['time_start'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').toISOString(true);
data[key]['time'] = moment(data[key]['time'], 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mma');
```